# Scala Lift: Box openOr does not seem to work

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, lift

I am following the "Exploring Lift" book and I've tried one of their example Snippets - the only difference here is that I don't use the MegaProtoUser class but instead rolled my own one. However, I get the following problem.

Here is my Snippet:

```
User.currentUser.map(user =>
  user.projects.flatMap(project => {
    bind("e", chooseTemplate("project", "entry", in),
      "name" -> Text(project.name.is),
      "actions" -> {
        SHtml.link("/manageProjects", () => project.delete_!, Text("Delete")) ++ Text(" ") ++
          SHtml.link("/editProject", () => currentAccountVar(project), Text("Edit"))
      })
  })) openOr Text("You are not logged in.")
```

And here are the compiler errors:

```
inferred type arguments [Seq[scala.xml.Node]{def seq: Seq[scala.xml.Node]{def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}; def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}] do not conform to method openOr's type parameter bounds [B >: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.xml.Node]]  

type mismatch;  found   : scala.xml.Text  required: Seq[scala.xml.Node]{def seq: Seq[scala.xml.Node]{def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}; def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}
```

If I replace openOr Text("You are not logged in.") with open_! then it works.

Why can't I use openOr in this context, what does this error mean? And what's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The error means the compiler wants a sequence but found a single element. Try

```
 List(Text(....))
```

instead of just

```
Text(....)
```

Comment: I've tried that already but then I get the following error:
    
    type mismatch;  found   : scala.xml.NodeSeq  required: Seq[scala.xml.Node]{def seq: Seq[scala.xml.Node]{def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}; def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}

Looks like the compiler does not know what it wants...

Comment: I think I remember an error like this... could you post your code in a form that lets me compile it? Except for that one error of course...

Comment: Kim, thanks for your time! Here you go: https://gist.github.com/1118420 I tried to shorten it down as much as possible.